# Start playing audio after 10 seconds, possible with javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio

I need an audio file to start playing after 10 seconds. Is there a way to do it with javascript?

This is the code of the sounds I want to play:

```
<embed src="sound.mp3" width="300" height="200" width="400" autoplay="true" loop="true" volume="100"></embed>

<BGSOUND SRC="sound.wav" LOOP="2" AUTOSTART="true">
```

I'm sure whether the code is cross-browser that's why I'm playing the sound twice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for `setTimeOut` function in javascript.